# Unity Photon doesn't add physics to the second connection

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to make a multiplayer air hockey game in Unity, but encountered some problems. When the first user creates the room, the hockey puck is spawned along with the first player's mallet (the object you hit the puck with). When the second player connects to the Photon server, their mallet is spawned.

The issue is when the second player hits the puck with his mallet, the Rigidbody physics don't work on the puck. The puck slides right along the mallet, but doesn't bounce off the mallet.

If I spawn both the puck and the mallet each time a user joins/creates the room, the physics work ONLY for the items the user spawned. For example: If Player1 spawned mallet1 and puck1, the physics work on their own objects. If player2 spawned mallet2 and puck2, the physics work on their own objects. But player1's mallet physics won't work with player2's puck.

I am new to Unity, so I don't know what part of the code to post. But this is the code where I spawn the items:

```
private void Start() {
     Vector2 puckPosition = new Vector2(0,0);
     Vector2 randPos = new Vector2(Random.Range(minX, maxX), Random.Range(minY, maxY));

     if(CreateAndJoinRooms.intHold == 0) { // If the user created the room, the result is 0
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(puckPrefab.name, puckPosition, Quaternion.identity);
     }

     PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerPrefab.name, randPos, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

**Here is my player movement script:**

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    bool wasJustClicked = true;
    bool canMove;
    Vector2 playerSize;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Transform PlayerBoundary;
    Boundary playerBoundary;
    PhotonView view;

    struct Boundary
    {
        public float Up, Down, Left, Right;

        public Boundary(float up, float down, float left, float right)
        {
            Up = up; Down = down; Left = left; Right = right;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        view = GetComponent<PhotonView>();

        PlayerBoundary = GameObject.FindWithTag("BoundaryHolder").transform;
        playerSize = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.extents;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        playerBoundary = new Boundary(PlayerBoundary.GetChild(0).position.y,
                                      PlayerBoundary.GetChild(1).position.y,
                                      PlayerBoundary.GetChild(2).position.x,
                                      PlayerBoundary.GetChild(3).position.x);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

            if (wasJustClicked)
            {
                wasJustClicked = false;

                if ((mousePos.x >= transform.position.x && 
                     mousePos.x < transform.position.x + playerSize.x ||
                     mousePos.x <= transform.position.x && 
                     mousePos.x > transform.position.x - playerSize.x) &&
                    (mousePos.y >= transform.position.y && 
                     mousePos.y < transform.position.y + playerSize.y ||
                     mousePos.y <= transform.position.y && 
                     mousePos.y > transform.position.y - playerSize.y))
                {
                    canMove = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    canMove = false;
                }
            }

            if (canMove)
            {
                Vector2 clampedMousePos = 
                    new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(mousePos.x, playerBoundary.Left, playerBoundary.Right),
                                Mathf.Clamp(mousePos.y, playerBoundary.Down, playerBoundary.Up));
                rb.MovePosition(clampedMousePos);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            wasJustClicked = true;
        }
    } 
}
```

**Mallet Prefab:**

[image: Mallet]

**Puck Prefab:**

[image: Puck]

Comment: That sounds like an ownership problem. Can you spawn the puck with server auth? (So it does not belong to either player)

Comment: How do I do that? Doesn't Instantiate spawn it to the server?

Comment: Not sure if that is the case for Photon or even the error. The documentation points to the PhotonView component: https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_view.html#a095064b4f27d379efe725ac06aa49379